# How to refresh a TableViewer in Eclipse RCP Application

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, jface, tableviewer

I’m using JFace viewer Framework in my eclipse rcp application, I’ve created a Table Viewer, which populates some data .My view has a refresh button below tableviewer, when I select a row in tableviewer  and trigger refresh button the selected row still appears in gray color.
Scenario is depicted below
Before selecting a row
[image: Before selecting row]
After selecting a row
[image: After selecting a row]
After refresh
[image: After refresh]
In what way can i remove the gray background as in the above figure and make it as 1st image.
My refresh button listener code is simple which has

```
viewer.refresh();
```

as a workaround i tried implementing methods like

```
viewer.getTable().redraw();
viewer.getTable().setRedraw(true);
```

which doesn't work, is there a solution to refresh it or should I refresh the view totally
*Note: My Execution environment is windows xp*

Comment: That gray bar is an indicator to the user to show which row was previously selected.  It's a feature, not a bug.

Comment: And it is only present on some platforms. E.g. you don't see the grey bar under OSX...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That gray line is *current*, not previous selection. It's gray because table is not in focus. Use `setSelection(StructuredSelection.EMPTY)`.

Answer (score 4):

If you create the table with the style flag `SWT.HIDE_SELECTION` the table will not show its selection when it loses focus. I.e. it will look like your first image.